# Forest Package (trees) - Direction of the branch

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, linguistics

[image]

I'm trying to do some branches at the east of the node 'Raiz' (as is demonstrated in the image). I've tried use grow=east, but it didn't work. Thanks!!

Here is what I used:

```
\documentclass[article]
\usepackage{forest} 
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}

    [Raiz
    [laríngeo [vozeado]]
    [lateral]
    [nasal]
    [Cavidade Oral
    [P.A.C
    [LABIAL]
    [CORONAL[anterior]]
    [DORSAL[recuado]]
    ]
    [distensão retardada]
    [contínuo]
    ]
    ]


\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

I don't know how to put [+consoante] and [soante] in `Raiz'. I also don't know how to keep [   ] between the words as presented in the image.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could aou add your code as ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). It will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that illustrates your problem.

Comment: \documentclass[showtrims, 10pt]{memoir} \usepackage{forest} \begin{document} \begin{forest}
 
 [Raiz
 [laríngeo [vozeado]]
 [lateral]
 [nasal]
 [Cavidade Oral
 [P.A.C
 [LABIAL]
 [CORONAL[anterior]]
 [DORSAL[recuado]]
 ]
 [distensão retardada]
 [contínuo]
 ]
 ]
 

\end{forest} \end{document}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like that?

```
\documentclass[showtrims, 10pt]{memoir} 
\usepackage{forest} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{forest} 
 [Raiz,blue!50!green 
   [laríngeo 
     [vozeado]
     ] 
   [lateral] 
   [nasal] 
   [Cavidade Oral 
      [P.A.C 
        [LABIAL] 
        [CORONAL
          [anterior]
          ] 
        [DORSAL
          [recuado]
          ] 
        ] 
      [distensão retardada] 
      [contínuo] 
    ]
    [{[soante]},before drawing tree={y=0cm,x=1cm},blue!50!green,edge=blue!50!green,anchor=west] 
    [{[+consoante]},before drawing tree={y=0.95cm,x=1cm},blue!50!green,edge=blue!50!green,anchor=north west] 
  ] 
\end{forest} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
% maybe this?
\documentclass[showtrims, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{forest} 
 [Raiz,blue!50!green 
   [Laríngeo 
     [{[vozeado]}]
     ] 
   [{[lateral]}] 
   [{[nasal]}] 
   [Cavidade Oral 
      [P.A.C 
        [LABIAL] 
        [CORONAL
          [{[anterior]}]
          ] 
        [DORSAL
          [{[recuado]}]
          ] 
        ] 
      [{[distensão retardada]}] 
      [{[contínuo]}] 
    ]
    [{[soante]},before drawing tree={y=0cm,x=1cm},blue!50!green,edge=blue!50!green,anchor=west] 
    [{[+consoante]},before drawing tree={y=0.95cm,x=1cm},blue!50!green,edge=blue!50!green,anchor=north west] 
  ] 
\end{forest} 
\end{document}
```

The curly brackets around nodes such as `[nasal]` are necessary to get the square brackets typeset in the node, rather than being parsed by Forest as part of the specification of the tree's structure.

[image: solution including square brackets in nodes]

Comment: This was supposedly be a nice indented code, why it becomes so horrible?

Comment: What is the differece to the accepted answer?

Comment: @dexteritas It will get the formatting of some nodes right, whereas the accepted answer gets them wrong, where 'right' and 'wrong' are understood as agreeing or disagreeing with the OP's target image.